# Is it possible to move a UIView and not its subviews?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView added as a subview to my main view. I also have a series of textfields in the main view, so the picker view covers some up. So I was wondering if it is possible to move the main view (containing textfields) while the picker view (subview added to main view) remains stationary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this would be to move the subview by the same amount in the opposite direction, negating the child view's movement. So, for example, if I move the parent's x origin +42 pixels, I should move the child's x origin -42 pixels. This can be encapsulated pretty easily into a single call.